# Why does the Chabad nusach omit "Tzur Yisroel" before Shemoneh Esrei?

Tags: prayer-book, chabad, nuschaot, nusach-sefard, nusach-ari

In the bracha right before the Amidah during Shacharis, Nusach Ashkenaz and many variations of Nusach Sefard have:

> שִׁירָה חֲדָשָׁה שִׁבְּחוּ גְאוּלִים לְשִׁמְךָ עַל שפַת הַיָּם. יַחַד כֻּלָּם הודוּ וְהִמְלִיכוּ וְאְָמְרוּ: ה' יִמְלךְ לְעולָם וָעֶד: **צוּר יִשרָאֵל. קוּמָה בְּעֶזְרַת יִשרָאֵל. וּפְדֵה כִנְאֻמֶךָ יְהוּדָה וְיִשרָאֵל.** [וְנֶאֱמַר:] גּאֲלֵנוּ ה' צְבָאות שְׁמו קְדושׁ יִשרָאֵל: בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה', גָּאַל יִשרָאֵל

However, the Chabad nusach and Nusach Edot Hamizrach omit the bolded words. Since nusach Chabad is techincally a variation Nusach Sefard, why is "Tzur Yisroel" omitted from the text?

Additionally, is this just in Nusach Chabad or do other Nusach Sefard versions omit these words? All of the "universal" (not belonging to a particular Chasdic dynasty or Rebbe) Sefard siddurim I've seen and davened from included the words.

Comment: Sephardic nussach, on which Arizal Siddur is build  nussach has no tsur Israel. The Siddur of Rav Shneur Salman from Ladi follows more the Sephardic nussach than others

Comment: Ironically, in many old Nusach Ashkenaz Siddurim "Tzur Yisrael...veYisrael" was the _only_ line in that paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a condensation of the explanation in the book שער הכולל ([page 25, paragraph 19](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16002&st=&pgnum=42)): The *brakhah* Emet ve-Yatziv is known to have the nature of being a blessing of *hoda'ah* (thankful acknowledgment), not  *baqashah* (petition), so that that line of poetry, which is petitionary, seems like an insertion that doesn't fit.

Comment: Is "Shirah Chadashah" part of the bracha of "Emes V'Yatziv"?

Comment: yes, @ezra, the blessing begins with the words "emes ve-yatziv" and ends with the words "barukh atah hashem ga'al yisra'el".