# Are there other Chasidim who omit "Tzur Yisroel" besides Chabad?

Tags: prayer-book, chabad, nuschaot, nusach-sefard

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85880/why-does-the-chabad-nusach-omit-tzur-yisroel-before-shemoneh-esrei) I asked earlier on this site.

All Nusach Sfard siddurim I have ever seen, with exception to the Chabad siddur, include the line of Tzur Yisroel, in accordance with the traditional Ashkenazi nusach, before the Tefillah of Shacharis.

Are there any other Chasidim who omit Tzur Yisroel just like the Chabad nusach?

**Note:** Sephardim do not say Tzur Yisroel either, but my question is not about them. This is because the line is unique to Ashkenazi nusachos (so I assume).

Comment: Jekkes don't say  גאלנו ה׳ צבקות שמו קדוש ישראל, not that it's particularly relevant to the OP

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - But I always love learning about Jeckes. :)

Comment: yes there are at least some but those would but chassidic groups that were originally part of chabad and then became separate based on disagreements over leadership. the split being based on leadership rather than minhag it would be reasonable to think they retained the same nusach. Today I'm not sure how many of these are still around as most rejoined chabad over time. One such notable group is known as melachim.

Comment: @Laser123 I am aware of these Chabad "split-off" groups such as the Malachim and the Liadiers but to be honest I am not interested in them. They are unfortunately dying Chasidic groups, with most either joining Chabad-Lubavitch or Satmar.

Comment: there are chassidim who use this nusach al pi ari zal and there are chassidim  who use kesser nehoira (nusach sefard. munkatch have their own siddur. I'm not sure how different it is). Why chose this one thing to ask about being different in some chassidic siddurim?